# oauth issue with basecamp

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, sinatra, basecamp

I'm getting the following error:

> --- :error: 'Unsupported type: nil. We support user_agent and web_server.'

when I try to redirect using this url:

```
https://launchpad.37signals.com/authorization/new?client_id=<client_ID>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9292/oauth/callback&response_type=code
```

Here's the code I'm using

```
class Client < Sinatra::Base
  get '/oauth' do
    redirect ::Base_Camp.oauth.auth_url
  end
end
```

edit: Also I changed `response_type` to `token`  and no change

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the url fields was wrong, should be `type` not `response_type`.